# How to get a item with the highest score from a list

Tags: list, haskell, max

I have a list in Haskell with a `[(item, score)]` structure.

```
highestScoreItem :: [(Item, Int)] -> Item
```

`highestScoreItem` is a function which takes a list of (Item, Int), and returns the item with the highest score.

I tried head tail recursion, yet still cannot get the function done. Filter and List Comprehension both seem to be the right way to do it but I am definitely not advanced enough to use this well....

Any help please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Filter and List Comprehension both seem to be the right way.

No. You want to reduce your list to a single element `(Item, Int)` and use `fst`. That's not a filter, but a fold.

There's [`maximumBy`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-List.html#v:maximumBy) in `Data.List`:

```
maximumBy :: (a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> a
```

If you had a function

```
compareScore :: (Item, Int) -> (Item, Int) -> Ordering
```

that compares two pairs `(Item, Int)` based on `snd`, you could use it like this:

```
highestScoreItem = fst . maximumBy compareScore
```

Luckily, there's [`comparing`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-Ord.html#v:comparing) in `Data.Ord`, which enables you to compare something in terms of something compareable:

```
compareScore = comparing snd
```

And that's all you need. As exercise, try to write `comparing` and `maximumBy` yourself, and then try to solve the problem with `foldr` only.

Comment: Thanks! I have never heard of fold but it seems to be quite useful... just finished writing my own comparing and maximumBy btw

Comment: @Elliot: Folding is quite common. If you follow LYAH you'll encounter `foldl` and `foldr` in chapter 6.

Answer (score 2):

You have a list of tuples and want to select the maximum value based on the second element of the tuple.

You need to use `maximumBy` function along with a custom comparator which can compare based on the second element.

```
import Data.Function (on)
import Data.List (maximumBy)
main = print $ fst (maximumBy (compare `on` snd) [(1, 5), (2, 1)])
-- 1
```

Here,

`maximumBy` takes each and every tuple from the list of tuples and calls the comparator function, `(compare`on`snd)` we passed as the first parameter, to get the actual value to be used in the comparison.

We use `snd` function to get only the second element in the tuple for the comparison. So, `maximumBy` uses only the second element of all the tuples for comparison and it gets the maximum value. But you need only the first element of the maximum tuple. So we use `fst` function to get only the first element from the tuple.

Alternatively, you use `comparing` function from the `Data.ord` module, like this

```
import Data.Ord (comparing)
import Data.List (maximumBy)
main = print $ fst (maximumBy (comparing snd) [(1, 5), (2, 1)])
-- 1
```

Comment: very useful answer... good example of using maximumBy cheers :)